# Content deployment on adding/modifying/deleting items in a library from serverA to serverB

Tags: web-services, export, content-deployment

I'd like to deploy content from serverA (intranet) to serverB (internet). Some of serverA's data is not to be published to serverB.

I first thought I'd use the SPExport and SPImport classes to define what to export, but I figure that using a simple EventReceiver (on creating/modifying/deleting an item on serverA) to call SharePoint's methods on serverB through webservices to add/modify/delete an item could be an solution.

What are your thoughts ?

Comment: +1 Interesting question Thomas! I'd like to explore this further... do you want to give anonymous access (no login required) on an entire library, or individual items in a library?

Comment: The plan is to export entire libraries to serverB. We will only enable anonymous access on serverB (internet)